# Lm.wfit in Java

Tags: java, r

I am desperately looking for the analogy of R lm.wfit  written in JAVA. I found only Apache Commons similar thing public void newSampleData(double[] y,double[][] x)but it does not use weights for estimations, but weights are very crutial in my case. If somebody came across this problem before, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Would rJava be an acceptable solution? http://www.rforge.net/rJava/